# Exception in thread java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-data

When i run this thread i this result and i dont khow why

FirstThread is running

Loading bar page

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.threads.FirstThread.run(FirstThread.java:29)

And the code ,

```
package com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.threads;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
 import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
 import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
 import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
 import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
 import com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.domain.bar.Bar;
 import com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.config.AppConfig;
 import com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.repositories.bar.BarPagingAndSortingRepository;
 import com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.repositories.bar.BarRepository;
@ContextConfiguration(classes =AppConfig.class,
loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

public class FirstThread extends Thread {

@Autowired
BarPagingAndSortingRepository barPage;
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("FirstThread is running");
    System.out.println("Loading bar page");
    Page<Bar> bars=barPage.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 1, Direction.DESC, "id"));
    System.out.println("Bar page loaded");
    Bar bar=bars.getContent().get(0);
    System.out.println("Creating bar");
    System.out.println(bar.getId());
    System.out.println();
    //int a = 20;
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    System.out.println("Interrupt");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    FirstThread thread=new FirstThread();
    thread.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to tell us which line is line 29. And just think about what's on that line--what could be null that you might want to check for?

Comment: where did you initate barPage??? ahhh ok via Autowired...

Comment: `barPage` has an `@Autowired` annotation on it--it may or may not be the problem.

Comment: you check this? Page<Bar> bars

Comment: Page<Bar> bars=barPage.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 1, Direction.DESC, "id")); 
Bar bar=bars.getContent().get(0);
bar.getId();
return the last Id used
and i tested with Junit test and it work fine

Comment: Are you running this as a standalone program?? `@Autowired` doesn't work in a vacuum. You need to be inside a Spring container. If you're calling the `main` method here, then it's hardly a wonder `barPage` is null.

Comment: For right now, you should create your own `barPage` and not use `@Autowired`. In general, you should learn how to use Spring, which is not really a topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your program in debug mode and evaluate every method calling and variable in 29 line. So you will see which of them is null

As this code is started from public static void main - there isn't initialized any Injection context, and @Autowired annotation wouldn't work, so barPage is null.
In JUnit test it could work, if there were special annotations in Junit tests, which initialized Spring context.
Take a look here: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html

And always think about one rule. Beans can be injected (autowired) only in another beans. Your test-case isn't a bean

Comment: Page<Bar> bars=barPage.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 1, Direction.DESC, "id")); is null

Comment: "barPage" variable is null? So the problem is that there is nothing Injected @Autowired
BarPagingAndSortingRepository barPage;

Answer (score 0):

And this is the pagingAndSorting bean

```html
package com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.repositories.bar;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.domain.bar.Bar;

public interface BarPagingAndSortingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Bar, Integer> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Main method should look like this to have successfully bound to Spring context:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");    
      BarPagingAndSortingRepository barPage = (BarPagingAndSortingRepository)  context.getBean("barPage");   
  }
}
```